# Advanced regex handling of String

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's Say that we have a String which contains a text as follows:

```
Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni. Appello con lettura nominale.  (a)
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?" Tentativo in base al numero dei presenti.  (b)
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”. Test attitudinale. Verifica e confronto. (c)
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati (primo, secondo, terzo...)  (d)
```

What I would get is this:

```
Tempo 5 min:  Introduzione e presentazioni.           (a)
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?"                       (b)
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”.                     (c)
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati     (d)
```

---

NOTES:

- the phrase of type (a) must end exactly before the dot symbol  **.**
- the phrase of type (b) must end exactly before the question symbol **?**
- the phrase of type (c) must end exactly after the last quotation mark followed by the dot **".**
- the phrase of type (d) must end exactly before the first parenthesis symbol **(**

A scheme like this has been used (considering that el contains the text):

```
String el1 = el.text();
String[] e1 = el1.split("[\\.?(]");
String eP1 = e1[0];
System.out.println(eP1);
```

But unfortunately I can not do the matching of all and only the conditions listed above.

How can I do?

---

Let's Say that we have a String which contains a text as follows:

```
Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni. Appello con lettura nominale.  (a)
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?" Tentativo in base al numero dei presenti.  (b)
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”. Test attitudinale. Verifica e confronto. (c)
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati (primo, secondo, terzo...)  (d)
```

What I would get is this:

```
Tempo 5 min:  Introduzione e presentazioni.           (a)
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?"                       (b)
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”.                     (c)
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati     (d)
```

---

NOTES:

- the phrase of type (a) must end exactly before the dot symbol  **.**
- the phrase of type (b) must end exactly before the question symbol **?**
- the phrase of type (c) must end exactly after the last quotation mark followed by the dot **".**
- the phrase of type (d) must end exactly before the first parenthesis symbol **(**

A scheme like this has been used (considering that el contains the text):

```
String el1 = el.text();
String[] e1 = el1.split("[\\.?(]");
String eP1 = e1[0];
System.out.println(eP1);
```

But unfortunately I can not do the matching of all and only the conditions listed above.

How can I do?

---

It looks like there are some limitations by using the suggested patterns, at least when the string contains strange chars like “ as shown below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
            String text = "Livello 15\n"
                + "10 min: Test preliminare. Valutazione svolta nel corso del mese. Cosa significa svolgere questo test, e come possiamo riuscirci? (Vedi il materiale delle dispense del 1° gennaio 2008, pp. 10-12.)\n"
                + "10 min: “Test secondario: verrà svolto?” Considerazioni conclusive.\n"
                + "10 min: Indice di gradimento: com'è andata? Discussione. Invitare i presenti a fare commenti.\n"
                + "Tempo 15 min: Presenti e assenti, elenco promossi (Ann. 3:17; 1 Sem. 4:12). Trattazione basata sulle dispense del 2015, da pagina 71, a pagina 72.";

            String pattern = "([^.\"“(]*(?:[\"“][^\"”]*[\"”]?)?(?:[.\"“] (?=\\())).*";
            String result = text.replaceAll( pattern, "$1");

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The output is wrong on the 3rd phrase:  10 min: “

```
Livello 15
10 min: Test preliminare.
10 min: “
10 min: Indice di gradimento: com'è andata? Discussione.
Tempo 15 min: Presenti e assenti, elenco promossi
```

It should be:

**10 min: “Test secondario: verrà svolto?”**

Comment: Are those (a), (b), (c) etc. part of the sentence?

Comment: If you have exactly those four patterns of sentences, I suggest using four regexes and seeing which one matches and extracting an according part of the match.

Comment: Your examples and notes for (a) and (b) don't agree. Look them over and update.

Comment: 1) (a), (b), (c) are part of a String which contains a lot of text, including parts to be removed from the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example I can come up with this regex to make the trick:

```
(.*?(?:\.|(?<=" )| (?=\())).*(\(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ2hX8/2)**

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/lxFL4I)**

Java code:

```
String str = "Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni. Appello con lettura nominale. (a)\n\nTempo 20 min: \"Prova iniziale?\" Tentativo in base al numero dei presenti. (b)\n\nTempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”. Test attitudinale. Verifica e confronto. (c)\n\nTempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati (primo, secondo, terzo...) (d)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?(?:\\.|(?<=\" )| (?=\\())).*(\\(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni.(a)
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?" (b)
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”.(c)
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati (d)
```

Comment: Cool ! Thank you so much for your help! Just to understand more deeply the use of regex: can you remind me how it has been constructed?

Comment: @JAVA_FI take a look at this link ![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/C6vOt-ijik2MR2_I.png) since you can understand it better. Let me know if you have doubt and I'll be glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

This expression works for the conditions you described:

```
([^."“(]*(?:["“][^"”]*["”]?)?(?:[."“]|(?= *\())).*              
^^     ^    ^            ^      ^   ^ ^      ^ ^^-+             
||     |    |            |      |   | +------+ | Rest of line
+------+    +------------+      +---+  or with | (not captured) 
|Any char    Quoted text        ends    parens |                
|except      (optional)         with           |                
|                                              |                
+----------------------------------------------+                
           GROUP 1 (captured in $1)
```

It captures the text, with optional quotes, until the dot, closing quotes or opening paren. Te rest is also matched but not captured. So we can easily replace it.

---

**Code:**

```
String text = "Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni. Appello con lettura nominale.\n"      // (a)
            + "Tempo 20 min: \"Prova iniziale?\" Tentativo in base al numero dei presenti.\n"   // (b)
            + "Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”. Test attitudinale. Verifica e confronto.\n"    // (c)
            + "Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati (primo, secondo, terzo...)";   // (d)

String pattern = "([^.\"“(]*(?:[\"“][^\"”]*[\"”]?)?(?:[.\"“]|(?=\\())).*";
String result = text.replaceAll( pattern, "$1");

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
Tempo 5 min: Introduzione e presentazioni.
Tempo 20 min: "Prova iniziale?"
Tempo 10 min: “Prova secondaria”.
Tempo 15 min: Discussione di gruppo dei risultati
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HSUTCH25558)**